# Формулы в PHPExcel

Tags: php, phpexcel

Возникла проблема с работой формул в PHPExcel. Формулы записываются в значения ячейки, но чтобы вывело результат работы формулы, нужно нажать на ячейку в ней и нажать Enter. Иначе, к сожалению, не работает. Есть возможность осуществить автоматический вывод?

```
$sheet->setCellValueExplicit('A'.($i+6),'=СРЗНАЧЕСЛИ(S6:S'.($i+5).';"<>0"; S6:S'.($i+5).')');
```

$i из цикла

Comment: Перед записью формулы присвоить ячейкам формат, отличный от текстового

Comment: @vikttur Не подскажите, как именно я могу это сделать?

Comment: Присоение формата ячейкам не помогло. Есть еще варианты?

Comment: Найдено на enSO - https://stackoverflow.com/a/32273420/8799283 Однако учтите, что от за 5 лет API могло поменяться

Comment: @DaemonHK Видимо поменялся((

Comment: А вы точно Writer запустили? Судя по фрагменту, Вы работаете с текущим листом

Comment: @DaemonHK   Если я вас правильно понял, то у меня запущен он вот так:
$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel2007');
  $objWriter->save('php://output');

Comment: @ЮрийГалай вот и попробуйте запустить `$objWriter->setPreCalculateFormulas(); ` ДО `save()`. Если уже пробовали, то читайте документацию. К сожалению, я уже года 3 не использовал эту библиотеку, не смогу подсказать точнее.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32612148/phpexcel-how-to-calculate-a-value-based-on-the-data-from-an-excel-sheet-withou?rq=1 Тут я нашел ответ на мой вопрос

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32612148/phpexcel-how-to-calculate-a-value-based-on-the-data-from-an-excel-sheet-withou?rq=1
Тут я нашел ответ на свой вопрос

```
$sum = PHPExcel_Calculation::getInstance(
            $objPHPExcel
        )->calculateFormula($formula, 'S'.$row_next, $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCell('S'.$row_next));
```